# How can I sum and calculate the percentage (correctly)?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sum the object values from an array, then I would calculate the percentage of each value respect to the total.

Here the array:

```
[
  {
    "ratiototale": [
      [
        {
          "0": "0.4-0.5",
          "1": 294
        },
        {
          "0": "0.6-0.7",
          "1": 2228
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

By this I'm having the correct percentage only for the second object.

```
var getData = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/ratio/grouped',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data[0].ratiototale[0]);

                        let somma = 0;
                        for (var key in data[0].ratiototale[0]) {
                            myChart.data.labels.push(data[0].ratiototale[0][key][0]);
                            //myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data[0].ratiototale[0][key][1]);
                            var relativo = data[0].ratiototale[0][key][1];
                            somma += relativo;
                            var relative = (relativo*100/somma);
                            myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(relative)
                            //console.log(relative)
                        }
            console.log(data[0].ratiototale[0][key]);
                        //console.log(somma)
            console.log(relativo)


                        // re-render the chart
                        myChart.update();
                    }
                });
            };
```

The sum I'm getting it's correct.

Suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the sum before looping over the elements to calculate the percentage. You can do so using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like -

```
let somma = data[0].ratiototale[0].reduce((accumulator,currentVal)=> accumulator + currentVal["1"], 0);
```

And then loop over to calculate the percentages, like -

```js
var data = [
  {
    "ratiototale": [
      [
        {
          "0": "0.4-0.5",
          "1": 294
        },
        {
          "0": "0.6-0.7",
          "1": 2228
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]

let somma = data[0].ratiototale[0].reduce((accumulator,currentVal)=> accumulator + currentVal["1"], 0);

for (var key in data[0].ratiototale[0]) {
  //myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data[0].ratiototale[0][key][1]);
  var relativo = data[0].ratiototale[0][key][1];
  console.log(relativo);
  var relative = (relativo*100/somma);
  console.log(relative);
}
```

So, your overall code can look like this -

```
var getData = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:3000/ratio/grouped',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data[0].ratiototale[0]);

                        let somma = data[0].ratiototale[0].reduce((accumulator,currentVal)=> accumulator + currentVal["1"], 0);
                        for (var key in data[0].ratiototale[0]) {
                            myChart.data.labels.push(data[0].ratiototale[0][key][0]);
                            //myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data[0].ratiototale[0][key][1]);
                            var relativo = data[0].ratiototale[0][key][1];
                            var relative = (relativo*100/somma);
                            myChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(relative)
                            //console.log(relative)
                        }
                        // re-render the chart
                        myChart.update();
                    }
                });
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating your chart within the loop. This means when you do the first iteration of the loop, you add the first value to a total, then calculate a percentage of that from the total. However, because it is the only value within the total, it will be 100%.

You will need to get the total of all the values first, then iterate over the values again to calculate the percentage of each.

Answer (score 1):

U need to get the overall sum in a separate loop first:

```js
//First calculate the overall sum
var somma = 0;
for (var key in data[0].ratiototale[0]) {
  somma += data[0].ratiototale[0][key][1];
}
//Then calculate the individual percentages of each data-point
for (var key in data[0].ratiototale[0]) {
  var relative = (data[0].ratiototale[0][key][1]*100/somma);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map` as follows to get the array of percentages, this can only be done after the sum of `1` keys is calculated:

```js
let percentages = [];

function calc(data) {
  let somma = 0;
  for (var key in data[0].ratiototale[0]) {
    var relativo = data[0].ratiototale[0][key][1];
    somma += relativo;
  }
  percentages = data[0].ratiototale[0].map((key) => key[1]/somma * 100);
}
calc([{"ratiototale":[[{"0":"0.4-0.5","1": 294 },{"0":"0.6-0.7","1":2228}]]}]);
console.log(percentages);
```